# Connect to Socket.io server with standard web-socket client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible connect to socket.io server with standard web-socket client?
When connecting to socket.io server through socket.io client, Url started with **HTTP** but for web-socket clients must use **ws**.
so, if it is possible, how to connect to socket.io server and what is the url for connecting to socket.io server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socket.io` has a protocol on top of webSockets.  If you're going to use `socket.io` on the server side, then you have to use a socket.io-compatible client on the other end.

So, you can't use a plain webSocket client to connect to a socket.io server.

The socket.io protocol is [here](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-protocol).